# Is a request to check understanding on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481280/can-someone-confirm-my-isolation-level-understanding-please?noredirect=1#comment49041290_30481280) question involves the asker providing a summary of SQL database related concepts and requesting someone help check his understanding and correct any mistakes.

I'm not sure if this is on-topic. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have to admit I cannot make sense of the question in the first place. What are they actually asking there?

Comment: It would appear that they do not want to get a negative rating on the post so they are trying to determine if the topic would be construed as off topic.

If in doubt you could post here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions

This is where I'm typically told to go to when I get an not on topic post.